# Where to find the Neo4j shell in v2.0.0-M06

Tags: neo4j

I want to use the Neo4j shell. With the V1.9 release, it was in the bin folder of the installation, but since I upgraded to v2.0.0-M06, I can no longer find it. The bin folder only contains the following files ...

```
Directory of C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin

16/10/2013  15:38    <DIR>          .
16/10/2013  15:38    <DIR>          ..
16/10/2013  15:38                37 neo4j-community-user-vmoptions.loc
14/10/2013  09:38           491,016 neo4j-community.exe
16/10/2013  15:38               242 neo4j-community.vmoptions
14/10/2013  09:37        39,564,808 neo4j-desktop-2.0.0-M06.jar
           4 File(s)     40,056,103 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  16,272,773,120 bytes free
```

I know I can use the shell in the web UI, but I want to pipe input and output, and I can't figure how to do that except with the stand-alone shell. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer - in another question - [How to install Neo4j 2.0+ as a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837065/how-to-install-neo4j-2-0-as-a-windows-service) .

By downloading the zip file rather than the windows installer, I get all the .bat files, including Neo4jshell.bat. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community
jre\bin\java -cp bin\neo4j-desktop-1.9.4.jar org.neo4j.shell.StartClient [--file /your/file/of/stuff.cyp]
```

Comment: Tried that (but substituted neop4j-desktop-2.0.0-M06.jar as neo4j-desktop-1.9.4.jar does not exist). Still got an error message ...C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community>jre\bin\java -cp bin\neo4j-desktop-2.0.0-M06.jar org.neo4j.shell.StartClient
The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Tired again, but omitted the jre\bin before the java. I realised that the JRE_HOME environment variable will supply the path. This time the shell started OK. Thanks

Comment: Thought it worked, but it didn't. Added the -port 7474 parameter. Different error now - `non-JRMP server at remote endpoint`