# How to install Neo4j 2.0+ as a windows service

Tags: windows, neo4j

I am trying out the community edition beta of Neo4j 2.0 for Windows but I can't see a way to install it as a service. The only way to start Neo4j appears to be through neo4j-community.exe, but that requires interactivity to push the start button. The batch file that existed in the 1.X release is gone.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In reference to the answers suggesting to download the zip version of Neo4J. There seems to be an issue on the Neo4J site where the zip file can no longer be downloaded.

Comment: The direct link is http://neo4j.com/download-thanks/?edition=community&release=2.1.4&packaging=zip&architecture=x64

Comment: Broken in 3.0 again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354606/install-neo4j-3-0-as-a-windows-service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look here: http://www.neo4j.org/download/other_versions The windows version shows a .zip download.  In the bin folder there are the bat files.

Run it as administrator and use the `install` command to install it as a service.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Use the powershell method now (the bat files are depreciated). There is a good guide [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/deployment/single-instance/windows/)

1. Download the ZIP file ([download page](https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/)).
2. Unzip it to C:\neo4j
3. Open powershell as an administrator and use: `C:\neo4j\bin\neo4j install-service`
4. Use the same command for all other operations (ie. `C:\neo4j\bin\neo4j restart`)

**If you run in to problems check the following**:

- Are you running powershell as an administrator?
- Have you allowed powershell scripts to run (`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` - USE WITH CAUTION).
- Have you installed java and set your JAVA_HOME environment variable to the java directory (ie. C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65)?

**Old answer (in case it works better for people)**

1. Go to the neo4j download page, and choose other installs. Download the zip file.
2. Unzip it to C:\neo4j (not essential, but you can copy and paste the example scripts easier).
3. Follow the instructions [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.0-M03/powershell.html)
   . In brief:
4. Type: `Import-Module C:\Neo4j\bin\Neo4j-Management.psd1`
5. To install the service enter:

   'C:\Neo4j' | Initialize-Neo4jServer -ListenOnIPAddress 127.0.0.1 -PassThru | 
   Install-Neo4jServer -PassThru | Start-Neo4jServer

Answer (score 4):

To extend @LameCoder's answer with some more steps that I had to do:

1. Download [the latest neo4j 2.n.n](http://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/) zip file (not exe)
2. Unzip to the final location for this instance
3. Download and install [Java SDK 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) (8 is out but Neo says use 7)
4. From a command prompt `SETX JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80"`. This sets the environment variable globally.
5. In your Neo4j folder, execute from an administrator elevated console: `<PATH>\bin\Neo4jInstaller.bat install`. You will get access denied if you didn't run the console elevated.
6. If your environment variable was set correctly, it will install
7. Reboot so the environment variable is available to the service
8. Observe your service has started and is serving at `http://localhost:7474`

To run **multiple instances**

1. Edit `Neo4jInstaller.bat` to modify `serviceName` and `serviceDisplayName` properties
2. In same file as above, edit properties `org.neo4j.server.webserver.port` and `org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port` to distinct ports

To run on a **different host** to the app server

1. Uncomment the `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address` property in the  `neo4j-server.properties` file to expose the service hosts other than 127.0.0.1