# Install Neo4j 3.0+ as a windows service

Tags: powershell, neo4j

Anyone tried installing neo4j version 3 in windows as a service? I tired neo4j community version 3.1.0 and 3.2.0 alpha. I am getting following error when try to start the service.

Invoke-Neo4j : Failed to start service 'Neo4j Graph Database - neo4j (neo4j)'. At line:1 char:211 + ... t.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j start) + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-Neo4j

Answer (score 1):

Was able to run as a windows service by running this script with nssm.

`powershell.exe -Command "Import-Module C:\Neo4j\bin\Neo4j-Management.psd1; Invoke-Neo4j console"`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and got resolved in this way:

**you have to run your PowerShell as admin:**

- set NEO4J_HOME D:\neo4j-community-3.3.0 {Change it to your installation directory}
- Go to your installation directory:
- ./bin/neo4j.bat install-service {when you are starting your server for the first time}
- ./bin/neo4j.bat start

[Screen shot of my powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjrm7.png)